# Python3: How can I split a list based on condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I've found a lot of answers on how to split a list into evenly sized chunks, but I have a different problem

I have data formatted like the following.

```
> header1
line1
line2
...
> header2
line4
line5
...
```

And I want to group the lines under their respective headers.

Getting the headers is easy. `headers = [x for x in lines if x.startswith('>')]`

But that trick doesn't work with the subsequent lines because there's no way to know which lines were under each header.

Idealy, I would want a list formatted like `[[line1, line2], [line4, line5]...]`

I have a working solution using a while loop, but it looks ugly. How could I accomplish this using either list comprehension or an existing library?

Comment: Is that FASTA format?

Comment: Yes it is FASTA

Comment: You might want to checkout Biopython, e.g. http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#sec12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `itertools.groupby` with a custom key function that changes every time we see a new header. In this function, we increment `ctr`.

```
from itertools import groupby

lis = ['>a', 'b', 'c', '>d', 'e', '>f', '>g']

def group_by_header(lis: list):
    def header_counter(x: str):
        if x.startswith('>'):
            header_counter.ctr += 1
        return header_counter.ctr
    header_counter.ctr = 0

    return groupby(lis, key=header_counter)

print([list(l) for k, l in group_by_header(lis)])
# [['>a', 'b', 'c'], ['>d', 'e'], ['>f'], ['>g']]
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution most likely not the best, but here we are:

Sample data:

```
data = """> header1
line1
line2
> header2
line4
line5
""".split("\n")
```

The simple for-loop solution OP mentioned:

```
def parse(d):
    result = []
    chunk = []
    for line in d:
        if not line:
            continue
        elif line.startswith(">"):
            if not chunk:
                continue
            result.append(chunk)
            chunk = []
            continue
        chunk.append(line)

    if chunk:
        result.append(chunk)
    
    return result
```

And via indexing headers + slicing the array using the index (2 liner):

```
def _parse(d):
    index = [i for i in range(0, len(d)) if d[i].startswith(">")] + [len(d)-1]
    return [d[index[i]+1:index[i+1]]  for i in range(0, len(index)-1)]
```

Result for both `[['line1', 'line2'], ['line4', 'line5']]`